# Logarithmic inequality with $\ln \ln \ln (n)$ in the equation

Tags: inequality, logarithms, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve a graph problem where $n \geq 1$. I have found an online article [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse525/13sp/scribe/lec5-5.pdf), which uses:
$$\ln 6 + \ln \ln n - \ln \ln \ln n - 1 \geq \frac{\ln \ln n}{2}$$

I find it difficult to understand this part. I am rewriting the left hand side as:
$$ \ln \left( \frac{6\ln(n)}{\mathbf{e}\ln(\ln(n))} \right) $$
and now the inequality is
$$ \ln \left( \frac{6\ln(n)}{\mathbf{e}\ln(\ln(n))} \right) \geq \frac{\ln \ln n}{2} $$
If I take the exponentials of both sides, it can help but then things become even more complicated, since if left side is negative, then taking exponentials will change the inequality etc...

**Extra:**
In the same link, there is also a very similar step, which says for $\alpha = \tfrac{6\ln(n)}{\ln\ln(n)}$ we can show $-\alpha\ln(\alpha) + \alpha - 1 < 0$, and I think even $-\alpha\ln(\alpha) + \alpha $ is negative. I am trying to take the derivatives, hessians etc to see the behavior, but these are really dependent on  $n$ and it seems that $n \geq \mathbf{e}$ is needed. Even with that, I could not prove... I thought I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $n=e$. Then, the LHS is undefined (division by zero). So, you must have $n>e$. Anyway, multiply both sides by 2 to get:
$$\ln\left(\dfrac{6\ln(n)}{e\ln(\ln(n))}\right)^2 \ge \ln\ln n$$

Take out the outer-most $\ln$ to get

$$\left(\dfrac{6\ln(n)}{e\ln(\ln(n))}\right)^2 \ge \ln n$$
Divide both sides by $\ln n$:

$$\dfrac{36\ln(n)}{e^2\left(\ln(\ln(n))\right)^2} \ge 1$$

That is a bit easier to prove.

$$36\ln n - e^2\left(\ln (\ln n)\right)^2 \ge 0$$

Let $f(n) = 36\ln n - e^2\left(\ln(\ln n)\right)^2$.

Taking the derivative with respect to $n$ and simplifying to find when the derivative is zero gives:

$$36\ln n - 2e^2\ln(\ln n) = 0$$

$$n^{36} = \left(\ln n\right)^{2e^2}$$

However, we know:

$$n^{36} \ge (\ln n)^{36} \ge (\ln n)^{2e^2}$$

So, it will never be zero. Plugging in $e^e$ gives a positive value for the derivative, so the derivative is always positive and $f(n)$ is increasing.

$n=e^e$, we have:

$$f(e^e) = 36e - e^2>0$$

Therefore, $f(n)\ge 0$ for all $n>e$.

Comment: I read your answer now, that's a good one! Thank you so much! Can I please ask you why you tried $e^e$ at the end specifically?Is it because it is an easy point to show the sign of the derivative anywhere?

Comment: Correct, it was just a convenient number to try.

Comment: Also, the 'however we know part' have inequalities. Doesnt at least one need to be > strictly to conclude it cant be equal?

Comment: The final $\ge$ is actually > because $36>2e^2$, and for all $n>e$, $\ln n > 1$.